# A question about the residue field

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Hi there I have the following question and I don't know exactly if this is true or not. Let us suppose that we have a commutative ring with unit $A$ and a subring $B\hookrightarrow A$. Let us suppose that $\mathfrak{m}$ is a maximal ideal in $A$  and furthermore, let's assume that $\mathfrak{m}\cap B$ is another maximal ideal (in general it is just a prime ideal). Are the residue field of $\mathfrak{m}$ and $\mathfrak{m}\cap B$ the same one? Is this true for every prime ideal?

Comment: Consider nontrivial extension of fields $k\subseteq K$. Then $(0)$ is the maximal ideal of $K$ and $(0)\cap k = (0)$ is the maximal ideal of $k$. Yet the residue fields are $k$ and $K$, respectively.

Comment: Let us assume then that $A$ and $B$ are $k$ algebras being $k$ an algebraically closed field

Comment: Then pick $K = k(x)$ (rational functions in one variable).

Comment: Sorry but in this case, you have that the residue field of $k$ at $(0)$ is $k$ and the residue field of $k(x)$ at (x) is $k$ again, so it holds

Comment: I don't understand. The ideal generated by $x$ in $k(x)$ is $k(x)$, because $k(x)$ is a field. If you have field $L$ and an element $\alpha \neq 0$ in $L$ then ideal generated by $\alpha$ in $L$ is equal to $L$.

Comment: Pick $\mathbb{C}(x)$ (field of rational functions with complex coefficients). Then $\{0\}\subseteq \mathbb{C}(x)$ is a maximal ideal. Next $\{0\}\cap \mathbb{C}$ is maximal ideal in $\mathbb{C}$. Moreover, $\mathbb{C}(x) \cong \mathbb{C}(x)/\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{C}/\{0\} = \mathbb{C}$.